# How to send a POST request via WebKit

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

To navigate a WebKit WebView to a URL is quite easy:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[m_webView mainFrame] loadRequest:requestObj];
```

I can't see where/how to add POST data to any of these objects. How do one perform a Post, using a hosted WebView in Cocoa?

---

Sample code for the answer:

```
NSData* postData = postString;
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSString* contentLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [data length]];
[urlRequest setValue:contentLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
[[m_webView mainFrame] loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [`NSMutableURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableURLRequest) object. It has a `setHTTPMethod:` method.